# Finding the last digits sum with recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, computer-science, computer-science-theory

I'm attempting to create a function that will sum all the digits
and will return the sum of the summarized number.

Example:
For **Input** getNumValue(1589)
The **Output** will be: 5
Becuase: 1 + 5 + 8 + 9 = 23
And 2 + 3 = 5
So the output will be 5
Because we can't split it into more digits.

I did managed to create a recursion function that summarize the digits:

```
def getNumValue(number: int):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    return (number % 10 + getNumValue(int(number / 10)))
```

But I can't seem to utilize it to my cause.

**Btw**
I don't want to use any strings
And I'm trying to use recursion so far no luck.
I bet this is a known mathematic problem I'm just unfamiliar with.
Any advice?

Comment: ```print(getNumValue(getNumValue(1234)))```?

Comment: Should we call it `digit root` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even shorter:

```
def getNumValue(number: int): return ((number-1) % 9) + 1
```

The digit sum is always in the same remainder class mod 9 as the original decimal number, this applies recursively, and thus reducing it to one digit just is the remainder under division by 9.

The shift by `1` just serves the purpose that the remainder class `0` is represented by `9`.

Comment: That's incredible! Thank you!

Comment: [The Equivalence of Digit Sum Arithmetic with Modular 9 Arithmetic](https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/Digitsum00.htm) provides an explanation.

Comment: @DanielHao--you're welcome.  Should point out this is not a recursive solution as originally required by the poster.

Comment: This gives me error `getNumValue(15897478910)`

Comment: @RinshanKolayil : I get result 5 without error or warning, python 3.7.3

Comment: `1+5+8+9+7+4+7+8+9+1+0=59` =5+9 = 14

Comment: @RinshanKolayil : Yes, and 1+4=5

Comment: Ok understand the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can make a final check before returning the answer.

```
def getNumValue(number: int):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    answer = (number % 10 + getNumValue(int(number // 10)))
    if answer < 10:
        return answer
    return getNumValue(answer)


print(getNumValue(15899999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999))
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
9
```

Comment: nice catch. I was missing integer division.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if number is greater than 9. If yes, then call the function again:

```
def getNumValue(number: int):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    j=(number % 10 + getNumValue(int(number // 10)))
    if j>9:
        return getNumValue(j)
    return j
print(getNumValue(getNumValue(1589)))
```

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Without recursion:

```
def getNumValue(number: int) -> int:
    while True:
        total = 0
        while number:
            total += number % 10
            number //= 10
        number = total
        if total <= 9:
            return total
```

```
>>> getNumValue(number)
5
```

Answer (score 0):

pythonic recursion :)

```
def getNumValue(number=1589):
    ans = number % 10 + getNumValue(int(number / 10)) if number else 0
    return getNumValue(ans) if ans > 10 else ans
```

output

```
5
```